# is there way to know which container is using which gpu device?

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia-smi

Let say I have a docker container is running A,B,C and GPU 1,2,3. 
I can check the gpu process ID with

```
nvidia-smi
```

some times container itself hold the gpu memory after it used up. 
so I want to find which gpu container is running which gpu and restart it 
I can not kill the gpu-pid because I do not have the sudo permission.

 is there way to know which container using which gpu pid?

```
container A -> using gpu A
```